# Why does gettatr transform a boolean into a string?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model with a boolean field:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__tracked_fields = ['is_paid']
        for field in self.__tracked_fields:
            setattr(self, '__original_%s' % field, getattr(self, field))
```

I'm trying to track the change in this field before saving:

```
def set_original_values(self):
    for field in self.__tracked_fields:
        original = '__original_%s' % field
        original_value = getattr(self, original)
        setattr(self, field, original_value)
    return self.__dict__

def has_changed(self):
    for field in self.__tracked_fields:
        original = '__original_%s' % field
        if getattr(self, original) != getattr(self, field):
            return True
    return False

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_clean()
    if self.has_changed():
        if not self.can_be_confirmed():
            self.set_original_values()
    return super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when testing, I get specific results.

```
# THE FAILED TEST CODE

def test_has_no_changed(self):
    self.invoice.amount = 1
    self.invoice.is_paid = True
    self.invoice.save()
    print(self.invoice.is_paid)
    print(type(self.invoice.is_paid))
    self.assertFalse(self.invoice.is_paid)
```

Part of the test result:

```
.False
<class 'str'>
AssertionError: 'False' is not false
```

Of course, if I once again get an object from the database, the value in the field will be converted to Boolean

But before getting the object from the database, the test passes only this way:

```
    self.assertEqual(self.invoice.is_paid, 'False')
```

What could be the problem?

** UPDATE **

Problem in the `set_original_values` method.

If I do, as shown in the example, then the field value type is a string.

P.S. Thanks to everyone who puts a negative on my question, because it's so useful in solving my problem ...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr you can make the string to bool by using "bool(x)"  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool

Comment: @hansTheFranz, I know it. But I do not understand why this happens.

Comment: `getattr` won't change the type. Perhaps the problem is in the test which you haven't shown.

Comment: I can imagine, that it has to do with how boolean are represented in the database. Django might actually store the strings 'True' and 'False' to represent the values in such a field. Using getattr instead of direct field access might bypass the to_python conversion method in the BooleanField class and return the plain DB values.

Comment: No. Django does not do that.

Comment: You do however need to show the code of the failing test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like this:

Since `bool('False') == True`, I am forced to check for 'True' and 'False' separately

```
def has_changed(self):
    for field in self.__tracked_fields:
        original = '__original_%s' % field
        if getattr(self, original) is 'False':
            return getattr(self, field) != False
        elif getattr(self, original) is 'True':
            return getattr(self, field) != True
        else:
            return getattr(self, original) != getattr(self, field)
```

It's exactly the same here.

```
def set_original_values(self):
    values = {}
    for field in self.__tracked_fields:
        original = '__original_%s' % field
        original_value = getattr(self, original)
        if original_value is 'True':
            setattr(self, field, True)
        elif original_value is 'False':
            setattr(self, field, False)
        else:
            setattr(self, field, original_value)
        values[field] = getattr(self, field)
    return values
```

Now the tests are successful.